# Normalize JSON to a custom schema

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects with the following format

```
var arr = [
    {
        "productId": "123456",
        "productName": "Test Product 1",
        "description": [
            "This is delicious",
            "Suitable for vegetarian"
        ],
        "attributes": {
            "internalId": "091283"
            "category": "Dairy"
        },
        "order": 1
    }
];
```

And I am trying to map into something like below

```
[
    [{
        {
            "name": "productId",
            "value": "123456"
        },
        {
            "name": "productName",
            "value": "Test Product 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "description",
            "value": ["This is delicious", "Suitable for vegetarian"]
        },
        {
            "name": "attributes",
            "value": {
                {
                    "name": "internalId",
                    "value": "091283"
                },
                {
                    "name": "category",
                    "value": "Dairy"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "order",
            "value": 1
        }
    }]
]
```

I tried mapping simple properties before going further and now stuck at getting only the last property of each object in the loop.

[image]

Suppose I don't know what are the format of incoming data and how can I normalize the JSON object to the format I want?

```
normalizeJson = (array) => {
        for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            normalizedJson[i] = {};
            Object.keys(array[i]).forEach(key => {
                if (array[i][key] && typeof array[i][key] === "object") {
                    // normalizeJson(obj[key]);
                    // console.log(key + ' is object');
                    return;
                } else {
                    o = {};
                    o["name"] = key;
                    o["value"] = array[i][key];
                    normalizedJson[i] = o;
                    // normalizedJson[i]["name"] = key;
                    // normalizedJson[i].value = array[i][key];
                    // console.log(key);
                    return;
                }
            });
        }

          console.log(normalizedJson);
    };
```

Or is there any library I can use in order to achieve this?

Comment: That's not a valid object. Do you perhaps want an array of arrays of objects?

Comment: @iota thanks for pointing out! Didn't realize what I'm expecting is not even a valid object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var obj = [
  {
    productId: "123456",
    productName: "Test Product 1",
    description: ["This is delicious", "Suitable for vegetarian"],
    attributes: {
      internalId: "091283",
      category: "Dairy",
    },
    order: 1,
  },
];

function normalizeObject(obj) {
  var result = [];
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    for (let i of obj) {
      result.push(normalizeObject(i));
    }
  } else if (typeof obj == "object") {
    for (let i of Object.keys(obj)) {
      result.push({ name: i, value: normalizeObject(obj[i]) });
    }
  } else {
    return obj;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(normalizeObject(obj), null, 2));
```

This looping method called [recursion](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-recursive-function/). Which is loop by calling function itself.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. Didn't realize my expected output in above was not even valid. Tried with your code and it's now working perfectly. Thanks a lot